# Command Prompt Error when entered the command to access directory

Tags: cmd, path, environment-variables, windows-10-desktop

I open `cmd` `C:\Users\Anonymous>`

When I try to access something, it shows:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox is not Recognized as Internal or External command,
operable program or Batch file
```

[image]

Earlier, the `path` environment variable was empty so I put in

[image: Path]

Need Fix!

Comment: Yes, you do need to use the `CD` command. However, another big part of the problem is that any path which contains a space character must be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're just writing a path into command line.
I guess you want to navigate to specific folder. In that case you should use command `CD` (Change Directory) like this:

```
cd \
```

(used to navigate to root of your c: drive)

```
cd "Program Files"
```

(navigate into "Program Files" folder)

```
cd Oracle
```

(go into Oracle folder)

etc...

Alternatively, you can write all that in single `CD` command

```
cd "\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
```

To summarize: You're making a mistake by not using any command (hence the error *(...)is not Recognized as Internal or External*). `CD` is command, `"c:\Program Files"` is path, a parameter for CD command.

Comment: Thanks Alot For such Quick Reply!